# Turning weekly data into daily data in R

Tags: r

I have an economic series that is in weekly format and the data table looks like the following:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2014-01-07 | 14791 |
| 2014-01-14 | 14698 |
| 2014-01-21 | 14523 |
| 2014-01-28 | 16233 |
| 2014-02-04 | 14783 |

I would like it converted to daily data where the next 5 non-weekend dates are filled with the previous value, so that it looks like the following:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2014-01-07 | 14791 |
| 2014-01-08 | 14791 |
| 2014-01-09 | 14791 |
| 2014-01-10 | 14791 |
| 2014-01-13 | 14791 |
| 2014-01-14 | 14698 |
| 2014-01-15 | 14698 |
| 2014-01-16 | 14698 |
| 2014-01-17 | 14698 |
| 2014-01-20 | 14698 |
| 2014-01-21 | 14698 |

etc...

There are lots of online examples for turning daily into weekly or monthly, but nothing for the reverse. I am at a loss and looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R:

```r
with(quux,
  data.frame(
    Value = rep(Value, times = c(diff(Date), 1L)),
    Date = c(Date[1], mapply(function(fm, to) seq(fm, to, by="days")[-1], Date[-nrow(quux)], Date[-1]))
  )
)
#    Value       Date
# 1  14791 2014-01-07
# 2  14791 2014-01-08
# 3  14791 2014-01-09
# 4  14791 2014-01-10
# 5  14791 2014-01-11
# 6  14791 2014-01-12
# 7  14791 2014-01-13
# 8  14698 2014-01-14
# 9  14698 2014-01-15
# 10 14698 2014-01-16
# 11 14698 2014-01-17
# 12 14698 2014-01-18
# 13 14698 2014-01-19
# 14 14698 2014-01-20
# 15 14523 2014-01-21
# 16 14523 2014-01-22
# 17 14523 2014-01-23
# 18 14523 2014-01-24
# 19 14523 2014-01-25
# 20 14523 2014-01-26
# 21 14523 2014-01-27
# 22 16233 2014-01-28
# 23 16233 2014-01-29
# 24 16233 2014-01-30
# 25 16233 2014-01-31
# 26 16233 2014-02-01
# 27 16233 2014-02-02
# 28 16233 2014-02-03
# 29 14783 2014-02-04
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("Date  Value
2014-01-07  14791
2014-01-14  14698
2014-01-21  14523
2014-01-28  16233
2014-02-04  14783")

df %>% 
  complete(Date = full_seq(Date, 1)) %>% 
  fill(Value) %>% 
  filter(!wday(Date, week_start = 1) %in% c(6, 7)) 

# A tibble: 21 × 2
   Date       Value
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2014-01-07 14791
 2 2014-01-08 14791
 3 2014-01-09 14791
 4 2014-01-10 14791
 5 2014-01-13 14791
 6 2014-01-14 14698
 7 2014-01-15 14698
 8 2014-01-16 14698
 9 2014-01-17 14698
10 2014-01-20 14698
# ℹ 11 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: didn't know about `tidyr::full_seq`, nice